# Generating a Road Network by Code

Tags: anylogic

I am currently trying to generate a road. I wrote the following code based on the API and the procedure for generating a network in the process modelling library.

```
MarkupSegmentLine rs = new MarkupSegmentLine(-40, 125, 0, 5000, 125, 0 );
Road entryRoad = new Road(this, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, 1, 1, 0, dodgerBlue, rs);
presentation.add(entryRoad);
```

When I run the code, I get a null pointer exception. The code compiles when the presentation call is added, but is that actually the error? Should I be using another function, such as draw()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost right... you need to just add the road into a network that defines how your roads are configured.

```
RoadNetwork littleNetwork = new RoadNetwork(this, "littleNetwork", SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, true, ROAD_RIGHT_HAND, 3.5, gray, white, ROAD_LINE_SINGLE_DASHED, white, ROAD_LINE_SINGLE, true);

MarkupSegmentLine rs = new MarkupSegmentLine(-40, 125, 0, 5000, 125, 0 );
Road entryRoad = new Road(this, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, 1, 1, 0, dodgerBlue, rs);

littleNetwork.addAll(entryRoad);

presentation.add(entryRoad);
```